# Type 'Observable<Promise<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<myRec[]>'. Type 'Promise<any>' is missing

Tags: angular

So I'm intending to let NG to deal with subscription during the lifecycle of a component, let it auto-subscribe/unsubscribe.

Here is my service providing observable for calls to endpoint outside, **MySvc.ts**

```
import { Injectable  } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
const url = '...';
@Injectable()
export class MySvc{
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 
getAllRec()
{
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
}
```

**myRec.ts**

```
export interface myRec
{
  name: string;
}
```

My display component **MyPage.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MySvc } from '..MySvc.service';
import { Observable, of} from "rxjs";
import { myRec} from '../models/myRec';     
@Component({...})
export class MyPage implements OnInit {
  public allRec$: Observable<myRec[]>;
constructor(private MySvc: MySvc) {}
ngOnInit()
{
  this.allRec$ = this.MySvc.getAllRec(); // see compiling error below
}
```

> Type 'Observable<Promise>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable<myRec[]>'.  Type 'Promise' is missing the following
> properties from type 'myRec[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling `.json` in the reponse which as you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response returns a promise

Angular already parses the response for you, so you don't need do to that, so just remove the `map` from the `getAllRec` function and also parametrize the function so that angular knows that the response contains an array of `myRec` like:

```
getAllRec()
{
  return this.http.get<myRec[]>(url);
}
```

You can see here that this does not give you a parsing error: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vhrk6d?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Naturally I don't have your url so I cannot test the method itself but I think this should be good enough :)

Comment: Also @Jeb50 this may just be my opinion but I would really really strongly suggest you to stick with Angular's naming conventions, `myRec` being a type should be c`MyRec`, and also instead of `MySvc` use something like `myService` (though I imagine you are just using those as a POC, still this would help immensely in making your code more readable/understandable).

Comment: Great points including naming convention. Removed everything after `(url)` solves compilation error but it won't go out to API endpoint outside. :(

Comment: is it because you are not subscribing to it? remember that observables are lazy, if you don't subscribe to them they don't do anything simplest thing is to read your `allRec$` in the template by using an `async` pipe

Comment: see **MyPage.ts**, it does subscribe `public allRec$: Observable<myRec[]>; ... this.allRec$ = this.MySvc.getAllRec();`

Comment: and Debug shows execution goes from MyPage.ts to MySvc.ts. New to NG, sorry.

Comment: that is an assignment not a subscription, if you want to subscribe to something you need to call the subscribe methods as: `.subscribe(function)` for example I would suggest you to change `public allRec$: Observable<myRec[]>;` to `public allRecs: myRec[] = [];` and then change `this.allRec$ = this.MySvc.getAllRec(); ` to `this.MySvc.getAllRec.subscribe( recs => this.allRecs = recs);` I think that should work nicely :)

Comment: I hope I am understanding you correctly, the thing is that I cannot see a subscription in the code you shared (you do apply pipe but that does not subscribe or anything)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227128/discussion-between-jeb50-and-dario-piotrowicz).

Answer (score 2):

change

```
getAllRec()
{
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
}
```

to

```
getAllRec()
{
  return this.http.get<myRec[]>(url);
}
```

your type was wrong;